# org.jmock.Mock no longer available?

Tags: java, jmock

so I added all the jars from jMock 2.5.1

While attempting to follow http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-rmock/index.html

```
import org.jmock.Mock;
import org.jmock.cglib.MockObjectTestCase;
public class ServiceClassTest extends MockObjectTestCase {
    private ServiceClass serviceClass;
    private Mock mockCollaborator;
    private ICollaborator collaborator;

    public void setUp(){
        serviceClass = new ServiceClass();
        mockCollaborator = new Mock(ICollaborator.class);
    }

    public void testRunServiceAndReturnFalse(){
        mockCollaborator.expects(once()).method\
              ("executeJob").will(returnValue("failure"));
        collaborator = (ICollaborator)mockCollaborator.proxy();
        boolean result = serviceClass.runService(collaborator);
        assertFalse(result);
    }
}
```

however, it doesn't work? It cannot find org.jmock.Mock instead suggest Mockery. I tried using Mockery but it doesn't seem to allow passing an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial uses JMock 1, which is obsolete. In JMock 2, the `Mock` class has been done away with, replaced with `Mockery` and generics.

Instead of

```
Mock mockCollaborator = new Mock(ICollaborator.class);
```

you would do

```
ICollaborator mockCollaborator  = mockery.mock(ICollaborator.class);
```

where `mockery` is a field of type `Mockery`.

I suggest ignoring that tutorial completely, and using the ones on the [JMock website](http://www.jmock.org/).